# Perl is there any way to determine whether a text string contains binary data

Tags: string, perl, binary

Hi currently I'm on a project that needs to read some strings from a text file and fill these strings into an XML file. But in this file there are some lines containing binary data. Is there a way that I could check whether the string contains binary data?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the following regular expression may be adequate:

```
m{
    [^          # Consider the match a success if each of the following meta-characters do not match
        \w          # Match word
        \d          # Match digit
        \s          # Match whitespace
        [:punct:]   # Match punctuation
    ]
}x
```

In essence, the text must contain at least a (binary) character that does not match:

- `\w` - word
- `\d` - digit
- `\s` - space
- `[[:punct:]]` - punctuation

Comment: Thanks to **[Shlomi Fish](http://www.shlomifish.org)** for suggesting negation on character class.

Comment: `/[^[:print:][:space:]]/`

Answer (score 0):

Perl has file tests operators for this: `-T` and `-B`. Note, however, that simply because a string is limited to a certain set of characters doesn't mean it's what we think text is. It still might be binary data to whatever generated it.